# Correct way to initialize a const member

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

I am working on a graphics library and I am currently working on optimization. As far as I know (correct me if I am wrong), in the GCC/G++ compiler, read-only variables and constants are placed in the text section in flash (I am working on an embedded system based on an ARM processor) and this offers an efficient way to hold large chunks of data instead of depending on RAM.

Therefore, I need to initialize a const array declared within a class, this is my approach:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BITMAP{
    public:
        const uint16_t *BMP; // Image for this graphic object       

        BITMAP(uint16_t *bmp) : BMP(bmp) {} // This is where I initialize the const array

};

class GFX{
    public:
        void init_bmp();
        void render();


    private:
        // Object 
        BITMAP *bmp_image;

};

void GFX::init_bmp()
{
    cout << "Setting..." << endl;
    uint16_t *BMP1 = new uint16_t[2];  
    BMP1[0] = 0xFFFF;
    BMP1[1] = 0xFFFF;
    BITMAP bmp_image(BMP1);
    cout << "done!" << endl;

    delete[] BMP1;
}

void GFX::render()
{
    for( int i=0; i<2; i++ )
    {
        cout << i << ":" << bmp_image->BMP[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    GFX img;

    img.test();
    img.render();


    return 0;
}
```

The above code is giving me a segmentation fault whenever I try to read the contents of `BITMAP::BMP`. What's the correct to initialize `const uint16_t *BMP` in the above code?

Comment: Your problems appears to be `GFX::init_bmp`. It creates the `BMP` pointer then deletes it. It is no good outside of `init_bmp`. Maybe `delete[] BMP1;` should be moved to a destructor.

Comment: You can't initialize an array that will be stored in ROM by using new. Look into `constexpr`, and `std::array<>`

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues: `bmp_image` is never initialized, and you delete the array before reading it.

Instead of this:

```
BITMAP bmp_image(BMP1);
```

Do this:

```
bmp_image = new BITMAP(BMP1);
```

These pointers should be deleted in the destructor of each class, not before.

Moreover, you are not actually creating a constant array. You are creating the array dynamically, because you use `new`. One way to make it a compile-time constant that is placed in the text section, is to create a global array with the image:

```
static const uint16_t BMP1[] = {0xFFFF, 0xFFFF};
```

Then pass this array to the constructor of `BITMAP`.

Comment: Is there any way to do the equivalent of what you did  "static const uint16_t BMP1[] = {0xFFFF, 0xFFFF};" on runtime? The file needs to be opened from a .jpg so I can't really do it on code.

Comment: @LuisCruz No. Text section is part of the executable file. If you don't know value at compile time, there is no way to place it in the text section.

Comment: I mean, I know the values beforehand at compile time. But the files are too large to "write" the hex values and put it in a file (my computer gets laggy!). Is there a better way to do it? I guess I would need to write my own makefile to insert the images on text-section?

Comment: @LuisCruz One way to do that is to define this variable in a header file, and create the header file automatically with a script that reads the image file. This way you don't have to open the header in your editor. If you always use the same image, then you only need to create the header once. Else you could execute the script in the makefile.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that.. Doing a script to create the header file would be the way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> What's the correct to initialize `const uint16_t *BMP` in the above code?

You are initializing it correctly. The problem is that you are `delete`ing the memory that was allocated, which leaves the member pointer as a dangling pointer.

You can remove the line

```
delete[] BMP1;
```

to take care of the problem. However, managing dynamically allocated memory is fraught with problems. Prefer use of `std::vector`.